# My css doesn't work with Opera

Tags: css, wordpress, safari

I have a problem, and so a question :

My website ( http://www.marveylabs.fr ) displays correctly with IE, Chrome, Firefox, ...

But, with safari 7 and OS X, no css at all.

Can somebody explain me what please?

Comment: we can do nothing without a specific issue mon amis

Comment: The issue is the CSS... http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425251225-image.jpg
With computer or ipad, when the website is viewed with safari, no css is loading...

Comment: you are using wordpress right ?

Comment: what's the name of the theme you are using ?

Comment: Moesia, by aTheme.
Before, it is worked.. I just changed header.php and style.css

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following and let me know if it works :

instead of :

```
 <!-- Style sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php Exemple('stylesheet_url'); ?>" media="screen" />
```

try to replace this piece of code `href="<?php Exemple('stylesheet_url')` with the exact path url of your css stylesheet like so :

```
<!-- Style sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wp-content/themes/delicate/style.css" />
```

if this is works in **safari** make sure you don't have an Incorrect URL variable for `siteurl option_value (longtext type)` in your database

Comment: I did it, but I have only a windows8 computer, so I can't try :/
But now I have 2 style.css in my source

Comment: you can use an emulator

Comment: https://www.modern.ie/fr-fr/screenshots#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marveylabs.fr

I have the same problem .. :(

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/4a32a95ffd0355315d691566788f88e1ce49a4fd/macmav_safari_7.0.jpg

No css/js loaded I think

Comment: I did a backup of my website, now it works I think, and I'm going to make the same modifications, but check everytime :)
Thank !